# Render fullcalendar event ordering of overlapping events when start or end time is not same

Tags: fullcalendar

Currently I am able to do event ordering  with https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOrder based on custom priority of events but this worked only when events start and end time is same. 
Is there any way where I can order overlapping events when there start/end time is **not same** ?

Example:

Event1: start-time = 13:00, end-time = 14:00, priority=2
Event2: start-time = 13:30 and end-time= 14:30, priority=1

**I show Event2 should be one left and Event1 on right.**

Normally it is Event1 on left and Event2 on right according to their start time.

Comment: the documentation of the page you linked to explains how it works, and it's clear from that that no, it's not possible. The later event will always be on the right because, well, it's later. It's kind of logical. Not sure why you'd really care about changing it? To me, as a user, that would just be a little bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I know it is not possible and yes current full calendar is superb implemented somehow I want to modify. I am using event "eventAfterRender" to have custom implemtation with some shadow. However thanks  @ADyson for quick reply

Comment: if you want to change how it works I'm afraid you'd have to alter the fullCalendar source code and fork it to a new version, since there's no hook into it via the API.